# The set of bounded lipschitz functions over a compact is barrelled but not a neighborhood of zero?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I recently learned that Banach spaces are barrelled, i.e any convex, balanced, absorbing and closed subset is a neighborhood of zero ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrelled_space)). I'm having trouble understanding why the following example fails.

The space $C([0,1])$ of real-valued (uniformly) continuous functions over the compact $[0,1]$ is a Banach for the sup norm. Fix $M$ and $L>0$. Let $X$ the subset consisting of $L$-lipschitz and $M$-bounded functions.

On the one hand, I checked that (and evidently made a mistake somewhere)

- $X$ is convex: since convex combination of $L$-lipschitz is $L$-lipschitz, and convex combination of $M$-bounded is $M$-bounded
- $X$ is balanced: since $-X = X$
- $X$ is absorbing: for $f$ (uniformly) continuous over $[0,1]$, shrinking $f$ makes it more and more lipschitz, and more and more bounded, so $\lambda f \in X$ for some $\lambda>0$
- $X$ is closed: since uniform limit of $L$-lipschitz is $L$-lipschitz, and uniform limit of $M$-bounded is $M$-bounded

On the other hand, $X$ is compact (because bounded and equicontinuous, by Arzela-Ascoli theorem), so it cannot contain an open ball (open balls of $C([0,1])$ are non-compact by Riesz theorem). So it cannot be a neighborhood of zero.

So $X$ is a barrelled subset of a Banach space, yet it cannot be a neighborhood of zero... Where is the mistake?

Comment: The error is that a non-Lipschitz function will never become L-Lipschitz, no matter how much you scale it. E.g. no multiple of $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: Aaah thanks, how could I miss that... Cheers!